# webhook not receives a webhook event when setting up a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Iv'e followed this tutorial steps:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/app-setup

All the first steps passed with no issues:
Messenger platform added,
Web-hook configured and works,
Facebook page subscribed,

When i reach to `Test your app subscription` it seems nothing is happening...

Any idea what can go wrong?

Comment: Did you test this with a user that has a role in the app? As long as your app is not reviewed, it will only work for those.

Comment: Yes, i send the message from myself (administrator)

Comment: Check if your page was actually successfully subscribed, by making a GET request to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/ using your page token.

Comment: Yes it's subscribed: `GET->/v3.2/me?fields=id,name,subscribed_apps` returns `{
  "id": "179***",
  "name": "M's test page",
  "subscribed_apps": {
    "data": [
      {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=174****",
        "name": "M's first app",
        "id": "174****",
        "subscribed_fields": [
          "feed",
          "mention",
          ..
          ..
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
`
Using Graph API Explorer

Comment: Then I’d check server logs next, to see whether there was an incoming request.

Comment: :) no logs at all, when i postmen or when the webhook was verified the logs was fine.. Thank you so much... maybe you have more ideas?

Comment: Here, I would recommend to use 3rd party tools which exactly helps you overcome this troubles. At [amio.io](https://amio.io), you don't need a Facebook App so you can immediately start, you can easily set your webhook url in administration and also we provide you a logs where you see if we received any data from Facebook and if we were able to send them to your webhook.